# Multiplying a matrix with an extra element - representation

Tags: r, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

Since R does not have matrices/vectors with zero as an index, it is not very intuitive how to do this which is cleaner in Basic.

I will often have to multiply a matrix, say of size 3 by 5 with a vector of size 4 preceeded by a "1.00" as the first element. This first element was referred to as the zeroth element all these years (decades). Now I have to figure out a decent way to do this in R.

```
A <- matrix(c(2, -1, 4.2, 3, 0, -4, -2, 4.5, 2, 0.4, 4, 0, -1.5, 2, 2), 3, 5, byrow=TRUE)

x <- c(10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 25)
```

Now I should form a new vector `xx` which is with a 1 in the first place followed by the elements of x `xx <- c(1, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 25)`, and then multiply `A` with this `xx`.

What is a good way to do this in R? Echelon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either

```
A %*% c(1, x)

#      [,1]
# [1,]  166
# [2,]  136
# [3,]   84
```

or

```
A[, -1, drop = FALSE] %*% x + A[, 1, drop = FALSE]


#      [,1]
# [1,]  166
# [2,]  136
# [3,]   84
```

I prefer to the first one, not really because it looks simpler, but because in R, it does not use more memory as the second.

Comment: The first one is really clean and simple, but could not think of it. I am still very new to R.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this. I am new to Stackflow also. I have another stupid question on having common/global variables in functions. I will write as a separate question.